# TableView Rendering?

Tags: swift, uitableview, rendering

I have a table view that is rendering some static data into a UITableView but occasionally when running on a physical device the data is replaced with ? (see screenshot). I have listed the code below if anyone has an idea why this is occurring?

[image: Table View]

Here is the code for the table view

import UIKit

class OvenViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

}
extension OvenViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return GridData.ovenTempConvArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OvenCell.className, for:   indexPath) as! OvenCell
        let data = GridData.ovenTempConvArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFTemp.text = "\(data["f"] ?? "") F"
        cell.lblCTemp.text = "\(data["c"] ?? "") C"
        cell.lblGasMark.text = data["gm"]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat   {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    } 
}
```

Comment: What data are you trying to set to 'text' ie what's inside your array called 'data' im guessing that its not ASCII characters or something that won't render properly as text

Comment: static let ovenTempConvArray = [["f":"250","c":"130","gm":"½"],
                                                        ["f":"275","c":"140","gm":"1"],
                                                        ["f":"300","c":"150","gm":"2"],
                                                        ["f":"325","c":"165","gm":"3"],
                                                        [ "f":"350","c":"177","gm":"4"] ]

Comment: an array of strings

Comment: ohhh its because you are trying to get a value out of your array using a string then... surely you should be doing 'data[0][0]' if you wanted "f" not data["f"]